# In Bootstrap v5.0.0-beta1 what can I use for labels (BS 3/4)?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I want to use labels in Bootstrap v5.0.0-beta1, but how?

In Bootstrap 3, I'm using it like this:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<span class="label label-success">Success</span>
<span class="label label-info">Info</span>
<span class="label label-warning">Warning</span>
<span class="label label-danger">Danger</span>
```

In [v5.0.0-beta1](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/), which class can I use for label? I was unable to find any class named 'label' in Bootstrap 5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need to use Badge now.

Example:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<span class="badge bg-primary">Primary</span>
<span class="badge bg-secondary">Secondary</span>
<span class="badge bg-success">Success</span>
<span class="badge bg-danger">Danger</span>
<span class="badge bg-warning text-dark">Warning</span>
<span class="badge bg-info text-dark">Info</span>
<span class="badge bg-light text-dark">Light</span>
<span class="badge bg-dark">Dark</span>
```

Official reference : [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/badge/)